# create new unique ID in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table

```
id | entry | field | value
1  | 1     | name  | Egon
2  | 1     | sname | Smith
3  | 1     | city  | Los Angeles
4  | 2     | name  | Stephe
5  | 2     | sname | Mueller
6  | 2     | city  | New York
```

where `id` is the PK and autoincrements. Lines with the same `entry` belong together, they are kind of a dataset. I want to add new lines for a new `entry` (which should have the value 3).

My Question is: how can I obtain the next value for `entry` in a way, that it is unique?
At the moment im using something like

```
SELECT MAX(entry)+1
```

but when two queries are made at the same time, I'll get `entry = "3"` for both of them. I'm coding in PHP.

Comment: correct your database design. entryid should be primary key somewhere

Comment: You have a modeling problem not a sequence problem.

Comment: id appears to be a (surrogate) primary key, {entry,field} looks like a candidate key. It might be needed to split te table into two or three tables, which would yield an EAV model (which (often) is considered an anti-pattern by many people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sequence that you already got as a unique identifier at INSERT (don't leave this task to PHP):

```
INSERT INTO "my_table" ("entry", "field", "value") VALUES (currval(('"my_current_id_sequence"'::text)::regclass), 'any_field_info', 'any_value_info');
```

This way postgres will use the right number EVERYTIME.

Another aproach is to create a sequence and use it on INSERT as well, just use `nextval(('"my_new_sequence"'::text)::regclass)` as the value of `entry` and you can even use it as a default value.

If you need to know which value was used just add `RETURNING entry` to your `INSERT`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE alt_serial START 101;
ALTER TABLE "my_table"
ALTER COLUMN "entry" SET DEFAULT nextval(('"alt_serial"'::text)::regclass);

INSERT INTO "my_table" ("entry", "field", "value") VALUES (DEFAULT, 'any_field_info', 'any_value_info') RETURNING entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do some kind of loop that increments the entry every loop. If you want to add more lines with the same entry, pass more arguments to it in 1 loop.

```
class foo{
protected $foo = [];
public function set_foo($arguments = []){
$this->foo = $arguments;
}

public function insert_rows(){

$entry = // last entry from the db (number)- your logic here
$num_of_foos = count($this->foo);

$i = 0;

$query = 'INSERT INTO table(entry, field, value ) VALUES'; 
while($i<$num_of_foos){
  if($i>1){$query .= ',';} // adds the comma if loop repeats more than once
  $query .= '("';
  $query .= $entry; // entry number for the first item
  $query .= ',' . $this->foo[$i] . ',' . $some_Value;
  $query .= '")';
  $i++;
} // end of while loop
$entry++;
} // end of function insert_rows()
} // end of class foo

//now all you need to do is set the foo

$foo = new foo;
$foo->set_foo('lalala'); // sets one argument with new entry
$foo->set_foo('jajaja'); // sets another argument with new entry
$foo->set_foo('lala', 'jaja');  // sets two arguments with the same entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- create a sequence

  ```
  CREATE SEQUENCE table_entry_seq;
  ```
- Then, when you need to add a row with a new `entry`, get the next value of the sequence:

  ```
  SELECT nextval(('"table_entry_seq"'::text)::regclass)
  ```